# How to add iAd in app?

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase, iad

I am reading http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/iad-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app and I see that I need to set ios4 base SDK. In Xcode 5 laters base  SDK is 7.0. How to set that and other params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is nearly 4 years old. You definitely don't need to set iOS4 as base sdk. You should set base SDK as Latest iOS, and deployment target to the earliest iOS version you intend to support (I'd recommend iOS 7, but that's your call).